# Laravel 8 @extends with parameters not null condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i have a laravel blade template and i need to extends a layous with different values depending on parameter status.
I've tried the follow solution but it does not work.
It seems that always to be considered the first @extends but $patient is null so I expect the second @extends statement to be considered.

Is the following statement correct?

```
@if(isset($patient->id))
  @extends('layouts.app', [
    'class' => '',
    'elementActive' => 'patients'
])
@else
    @extends('layouts.app', [
    'class' => '',
    'elementActive' => 'diets'
])
@endif
```

Do you have some suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to clearly define when you mean when you say *"but it does not work,"*. What doesn't work? What's your expected outcome? What is actually happening? Also, it doesn't look like you're using `@include` anywhere in your code, so your title doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @TimLewis 
Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry in fact I was not clear, I wrote after a long day of work :)
I have updated my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
@extends('layouts.app', [
    'class' => '',
    'elementActive' => $patient ? 'patients': 'diets']
)
```